# Adding Sub Fields to a DescriptorProto.Builder Protocol Buffers

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have recently started working protobufs, found the following tough. Could you please help me out?

Sample Code:

```
DescriptorProto.Builder builder;
FieldDescriptorProto.Builder fieldBuilder = FieldDescriptorProto.newBuilder()
                    .setLabel(label)
                    .setType(type)
                    .setName("name")
                    .setNumber(1)
                    .setDefaultValue("value");
builder.addField(fieldBuilder.build());
```

Now let the type of the field is **FieldDescriptorProto.Type.TYPE_MESSAGE**. 
I have to ad subfield to the field built using **fieldBuilder**.

This should be possible because when I build a descriptor file for a proto file with a root message having a nested message with fields. And when I debug what I found is "A field of type message with its inner fields is added to the root message ", i.e., for the following message it is represented as rootMessage has a field subMessage(type = Message) with two subfields B, C.

Sample Proto:

```
message rootMessage{
      string A = 1;
      message subMessage{
         string B = 1;
         string C = 2;
      }
      subMessage sub = 2;
}
```

Typically I need something like

```
FieldDescriptorProto.Builder fieldBuilder = FieldDescriptorProto.newBuilder()
                    .setLabel(label)
                    .setType(type)
                    .setName("name")
                    .addField(...) // **This Part**
                    .setNumber(1)
                    .setDefaultValue("value");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea protobuf uses is to add a nested message and a field to the parent and link them by adding **setTypeName** in the field and add the nested message with the name given in the field **typeName**

```
DescriptorProto.Builder builder;
FieldDescriptorProto.Builder fieldBuilder =FieldDescriptorProto.newBuilder()
                            .setLabel(label)
                            .setType(type)
                            .setName("name")
                            .setTypeName("nestedMessageName")
                            .setNumber(1)
                            .setDefaultValue("value");
builder.addField(fieldBuilder.build());
builder.addNestedMessage(messageBuilder.setName("nestedMessageName").build());
```