# How to inject a new field into a generated message

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have a bunch of protocol buffers (v3) generated (legacy) messages. I can't change them (their protos). I use them both for transmitting data downstream as well as a data-structure within my application. For various reasons and uses, my application needs to know when it received those messages, i.e., a timestamp. The messages (and their submessages), however, do not include a field to store timestamps.

What I want is to take those messages on reception, inject a new 'timestamp' field (long or Timestamp, both are fine) into them, then pass them along inside my application, and, perhaps, onward to other applications downstream. I don't want to (and essentially can't) define a whole slew of 'shadow' (sub)message (backward compatibility etc.).

Protobuf's documentation says that I can do this. That it is straightforward even, and a 'good thing' about protobuf. No doubt.

But neither the documentation nor an hours long search on the internet, turned up a (Java) code example of, what I believe, should be a basic use-case (of DynamicMessage?). Or even just a basic step-by-step explanation of what you'd need to do, using what. I think found some pieces of puzzle, but lack too many others to make it stick.

I've been trying to something like this:

```java
public static <T extends Message> T injectTimestamp(Instant timestamp, T message) {
   // 1. Determine highest/free index number from message
   // 2. Extract message descriptor (builder?)
   // 3. Create new timestamp field using FieldDescriptor builder (?)
   // 4. Add new timestamp field to extracted message descriptor
   // 5. Build new message (type) (with timestamp) from old message using new descriptor
   // 6. Set new timestamp field with timestamp
   // 7. Build new message and return (yay!)
}
```

I can (kinda) do 1, 3, and 6; but the rest (still) eludes me.

I have written a (Java) wrapper to do this for me within my application (`TimestampedContainer<T extends Message>`), but that doesn't solve the problem when I want/need to send these messages to applications further down the software-stack.

**Clarification**
From the comments below, it seems my description of the problem is somewhat unclear. Sorry about that. Perhaps a clarification will help.

My application is somewhere in the middle of a data processing pipeline. It takes protobuf messages up-the-wire, processes and updates the data contained within, and passes them along to other applications down-the-wire.

The message schemas in the .proto files are defined up-the-wire, and out of my control; i.e., I can't revise them. The applications down-the-wire rely on those schemas in their business logic as well, so I can't wrap the received messages in new messages either, as in:

```
message MessageB {
   long timestamp = 1;
   MessageA orig_message = 2;
}
```

What I would like my application to do is to dynamically, at runtime, use protobuf's reflection and message generating methods/classes, and: unpack the schema from the received messages; add a timestamp field to the schema; create a new message (type) from that; copy the data from the original message into it; add the timestamp data; and pass it along (either within the application, or down-the-wire).

For example, going from:

```
message MessageA {
   int32 data_int = 1;
   // lots more data fields ...
   string data_string = 31;
}
```

to

```
message MessageA {
   int32 data_int = 1;
   // lots more data fields ...
   string data_string = 31;
   long timestamp = 32;
}
```

Whether the application down-the-wire use the newly added timestamp fields is entirely up to them.

In a way, I want to do a bit like what protoc does, at runtime, dynamically.

I think this should be possible; after all, the protobuf documentation says:

> Updating A Message Type
> If an existing message type no longer meets all your needs – for example, you’d like the message format to have an extra field – but you’d still like to use code created with the old format, don’t worry! It’s very simple to update message types without breaking any of your existing code when you use the binary wire format.

Comment: You cannot do this without modifying the message.  You can modify the message in a backwards compatible way that does not interfere with their current usages, but you will need to modify them.  Modifying the data passed around in a message without modifying the message definition is not supported by protobuf, at least without a message specifically designed to be used in such a way (such as proto2 extension ranges).

Comment: Thanks for your response! But to clarify perhaps, I *want* to modify the message, and the message definition as well. I want to add the timestamp field to the message, and that would naturally mean modifying the message definition (descriptor) as well. As in `MessageA' goes in, a newly generated 'MessageA' goes out, only it now has a timestamp field in addition to the other fields it had before.  Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @LouisWasserman is correct. The the **only** way that you should ever change the stubs and thus change "on-the-wire" messages (between peers) is to revise the protobuf message sources (`protos`) in this case by adding timestamps to messages that need it. Adding fields to messages ensures they remain (parseably) compatible but, of course, adding e.g. timestamps requires changes to the business logic. Code that uses earlier versions of the protos|stubs will continue to work (with new messages with the field additions) but the earlier versions won't, of course, parse|represent the added fields.

Comment: **But** you said you can't change the proto sources and you can't send messages with added timestamps between peers unless you do.

Comment: @BarthCrane: By "modifying the message," I specifically mean "modifying the definition in the `.proto` file."  I do not mean "modifying the definition of the message during your program's execution."

Comment: @DazWilkin: You are right, I can't make changes to the protobuf message sources (the .proto files), they are in legacy code out of my control. My application is middleware, it processes/changes the data in the up-the-wire messages, and sends them on down-the-wire. I want it to, at runtime, use protobufs' reflection and message generating logic to create new messages that include a new timestamp field. Whether down-the-wire applications use it is up to them, but they shouldn't have to update their business logic because the definition of the other fields remains the same. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take this step by step, see if I've got the problem understood.

> "What I want is to take those messages on reception,"

Ok, I'm assuming that means receive a whole demarcated message somehow, and you are parsing it using code generated from the original schema for the message. You now have an object in memory, of a class generated by the protoc compiler from the schema.

> inject a new 'timestamp' field (long or Timestamp, both are fine) into them,

There is no field in the object that you have in memory into which a timestamp value can be written. The options here are

1. Write another class that incorporates the original message class and a timestamp field. Create a new object from that, setting the message and timestamp field. Or,
2. Create such a class with a new message in the protoc schema

The latter would look something like the following, in your schema:

```
message TimestampedMessage
{
    long timestamp = 1;
    YourOriginalMessage msg = 2;
}
```

So far, both amount to pretty much the same thing.

> then pass them along inside my application,

That sounds like simply passing the reference to the object combining the message and timestamp around inside the application

> and, perhaps, onwards to other applications downstream.

That would best be accomplished had the extended class been created by a adding a new message definition to the protoc schema. This is because protoc has built you a serialisable class, other projects can consume them, etc.

> I don't want to (and essentially can't) define a whole slew of 'shadow' (sub)message (backward compatibility etc.).

And this is where I get stuck, and wonder what the real problem is. If there is a requirement to add information to a message and propagate it further throughout your system, you have to have a way of communicating the new information.

If the problem is that there's a lot of original messages, and you don't want to double the message count simply for the sake of a timestamp field, an option is a message that has a oneof field of , and a timestamp / long field for the timestamp. This means only one new message type, no transcribing of fields from one object to another field by field, and very little re-work in your application and throughout the system.

```
message TimestampedMessage {
  long timestamp = 1;
  oneof msg {
    // messages from your original schema
    YourOriginalMessageType1 type1 = 2;
    YourOriginalMessageType2 type2 = 3;
  }
}
```

This is even extensible - add more to the oneof. Importantly you're not modifying `YourOriginalMessageType1`, etc.

Apologies if this has gone down the wrong alley; let us know, see what we can do :-)

**In General**

One of the reasons to use something like Google Protocol Buffers it to facilitate agility in what information looks like within a system throughout development. If a bunch of messages had been defined without a field that, now, one wishes they all had, and one already had valuable data, then something like what I've outlined is a reasonable way to proceed.

Your code snippet feels like you're trying to programmatically do the work of protoc to some extent. The issue with it is, how on earth do you communicate the consequences / results to another part of the system? If you're dynamically creating new message formats without a schema, how does the rest of the system know what to do?

EDIT

**If You Have Some Control**

If you have some control of or ability to come to an agreement with the down stream consumers, you could pursue your own schema additions independent of the upstream. You simply have your own schema file that includes the original, and formulates a new message (probably a `oneof` idea as above). That way, the only thing you're taking control of is how timestamp is communicated downstream alongside the original message. If the controllers of the original schema want to update their message definitions, so be it; they can do so, but they won't be altering how you communicate timestamp.

It could get confusing if they add their own timestamp field, so there's still need for collaboration and agreement!

This isn't so far removed from what you're planning on doing anyway, though the way you're trying to do it feels like if you were agreeing it in a schema, you'd be appending timestamp to the end of each and every message.

EDIT 2 - Resolved

The resolution of this question is that, when one dynamically adds a field to a message object using the API GPB provides in Java (and C++?), that does not result in a description of the new field being wrapped up in the resultant wireformat data, propagated to and acted on automatically by a recipient of it (regardless of programming language). The description does not travel with the message data. This was the point of misunderstanding.

Thus the course of action originally being pursued by our O.P. BarthCrane would have resulted in recipients getting message data containing tags and values they'd not be able to parse or process.

Dynamic modification of the a message object within a program is no different in concept to editing the schema; every emitter / recipient of messages has to know to make the same dynamic changes, if they're going to be able to understand the modified messages, just as they'd otherwise have to be using code built from the same schema.

There is the concept of self describing messages, but you still have to have a starting schema that supports that and recipients that know how to programmatically build  a parser for them from the description received.

Self-modifying code: there be dragons, approach with caution!

Comment: Thanks @bazza for the answers. But yes, during runtime, I want my application to do (some of) the work that protoc does, and dynamically create new messages that include the same data as the received messages but now includes a new (timestamp) field as well. Unfortunately I can't add this field to the original .proto files as those are out of my control. Nor can I change the schemas in the way you describe, as down-the-wire applications rely on those and I don't have control over those either. Whether they want to use the new field or not is up to them. I'll add a clarification in my question.

Comment: @BarthCrane, hmm it feels like an awful lot of work on your part that no one is really asking you to do. One can look at schema as a kind of contract - deliver messages under the agreed format, everyone is happy. Sending a field not asked for could actually cause downstream issues (in my application area, it'd start looking like a security attack). I think that, all in all, there's no harm in carrying timestamp through with messages within your application, but I'd hold off propagating it using your way to other parts of the system, without explicit contract agreement (a schema update).

Comment: @BarthCrane, the other aspect of contracts are that they are negotiable. Make a proposal for a schema update; you're basically saying "Hey, I can add this and it might be useful, it's not much work, what do you think?". Could be quicker than writing the code your way. Adding the timestamp field officially to the schema's individual messages won't change anyone's source code, if they don't want to use it. Personally, I'd favour the `oneof`, because if one finds that there's a case for one item of metadata about data (your timestamp), there may be more to add. `Oneof` is less work then.

Comment: @BarthCrane, the kinds of metadata I'd routinely be putting in is timestamp, orig, expected destination, possibly a route-record (if it's a complex system), list of nodes that modified a message and when. It sounds bloaty, and not all of it is applicable. But, if logged, wiresharked, etc, one can learn an awful lot about the dynamics and behaviour of a system from such metadata, and it's often quite useful to have it.

Comment: I get what you are saying, but that might answer the questions of whether/if one should do this, not so much the question posed: "how does one do this?" And that only for this particular use-case (the actual one is a bit more complicated, but I can expand the answer myself). But there are obviously use-cases for this, as protobuf includes methods of reflection, dynamic message generation, updating schemas etc. As it should, if protobuf is a language-neutral provider of extendable and serializable data-structures between applications (ref protobuf documentation).

Comment: The problem I have is that I can't, for the life of me, find an complete example of how to do this (or something much like it) anywhere, either in the documentation, or on the internets. I can find snippets of it (e.g., how to build a FieldDescriptorProto, and add it to a DiscriptorProto, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008824/adding-sub-fields-to-a-descriptorproto-builder-protocol-buffers)), i.e., step 3. and 4. above; but not what comes before or after that. Protobuf's JavaDoc isn't much help there either.

Comment: The Java library provides the DynamicMessage [class](https://protobuf.dev/reference/java/api-docs/com/google/protobuf/DynamicMessage.html) for doing this. It is also mentioned [here](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/proto3/#updating) and [here](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/techniques/#self-description) in the documentation. Part of how to do it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008824/adding-sub-fields-to-a-descriptorproto-builder-protocol-buffers?noredirect=1&lq=1). So I am sure you can do this, I just need an example of how exactly.

Comment: As for the schema/contract issue, I don't think it's try to say the dynamically added field is completely impossible to access. Any application downstream can still use reflection (e.g., `null != message.getDescriptorForType().findFieldByName("timestamp")`) to see if the added field exists, because the newly generated dynamic message contains (and serializes) the message descriptor. They would just need to know that it could possibly exist, and what it is called. Not ideal, and perhaps not "safe", I agree, but the best I can do, given the constraints I'm developing under?

Comment: @BarthCrane - hadn't spotted the dynamic message part of the C++ API before, or the self describing message. However, I think we're there now. It feels like you're trying to get something with the properties of a self describing message, without actually having schema support for doing that. If you just dynamically add a new field to a message object, a recipient of the message working to your fixed schema has no idea what the new field is; the description of it does not travel. They just experience an unknown tag / value.

Comment: @BarthCrane The only way that a recipient could understand that you've added a field is if the message as described in the schema (that you cannot change) already had a field of type FileDescriptorSet, and the recipient knew that it had first to consume that to build a parser for whatever came next. But, you've probably not got that.

Comment: Yes, the penny finally dropped. I misunderestimated that protobuf doesn't natively transmit the 'FileDescriptorSet' down-the-wire, and what the consequences of that are. I can do something like what I described programmatically (using 'DynamicMessage', or 'protobuf-dynamic'), by using the Self-Describing Messages technique. But that would require a new "contract" with the down-the-wire applications, using perhaps a 'oneof' or 'any' type for the wrapped messages. At which point the original objective (to do so without requiring changes down-the-wire) will not have been achieved anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the time and effort you put in helping me wrap my head around this! I'm sorry that it took me so long.

Comment: @BarthCrane, no worries, glad to have been of help. I've learned a fair bit too - I'd not caught up with the C++ implementation supporting dynamic messages! It's enjoyable discerning unstated assumptions :-) Still, this question can remain a useful exploration of the topic for others to find and learn from too :-) Good luck going forward!

Answer (score 0):

Automatically using the first non-used id sounds like a bad idea. I'd use a consistent ID that is unique/reserved, e.g., a high number like 9999.

You can modify the raw bytes on the wire to make it look like there is a new field. This does not require any changes to the message schema, e.g., let's say you are using Java and writing length-delimited messages:

```
CodedOutputStream output;

// Write a larger delimiter that includes the manually added field
var newLength = CodedOutputStream.computeFixed32Size(9999, timestamp) + originalMsg.getSerializedSize();
output.writeUInt32NoTag(newLength);

// Write the new timestamp field
output.writeFixed64(9999, timestamp);

// Append the fields of the original message
originalMsg.writeTo(output);
```

Any user that wants to use it can just add a root-message-level field:

```
optional uint64 timestamp = 9999;
```

If you don't need to look at the message, you can do it with the raw input bytes and don't need to marshall the message at all.